# Redirect non-www to www WITHOUT forcing https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a client who has an http SEO'ed wordpress site, with https AdWords static html landing pages (I know - don't ask).
They want to 301 all non-www to www. I tried the following htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works great for getting all URLs redirected to www from non-www. However it also changes all https URLs to http.

How can I get it so that all non-www redirect to www, but http and https are NOT affected.

For example:

**http://example.com/seo-page -> http://www.example.com/seo-page**

and

**https://example.com/ppc-page -> https://www.example.com/ppc-page**

Thanks

EDT: 
Existing .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* - [E=CANONICAL:http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI},NE]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule .* - [E=CANONICAL:https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI},NE]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I guess you’ll have to do this separately for each case, because there isn’t really a way to get this info as a back reference or something like that AFAIK. An additional RewriteCond that checks for HTTPS, preceding a Rule that rewrites to `https://...` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. Any idea how to do this? I'd rather not do them individually as there are about 100 https ppc landing pages - and over 400 http SEO pages.

Comment: By each case I meant HTTP and HTTPS, not each individual URL ...

Comment: Ok. How? I have rather limited knowledge of .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Save `.htaccess` and try this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.) 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s on:(s)
RewriteRule .* - [E=CANONICAL:http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI},NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s on:(s)
RewriteRule .* - [E=CANONICAL:http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI},NE]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it still forces the https pages to http.

Comment: All caches cleared, including the CDN. Using this code I have the following: '**http://example**' redirects to '**http://www.example**'. But '**https://example**' still goes to '**http://www.example**'.

Comment: paste the rest of .htaccess file

Comment: Edited the original question

Comment: @JoshN see the updated code , clear cache the test it

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thank you ever so much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress then you don't need to add any code in .htaccess file. You can redirect entire site by entering www or nonwww url in settings.

**Login** to **wp-admin**
Then hit **settings** button and visit in
the **3rd field name** (WordPress Address (URL)) enter your URL where you want to redirect website. and paste the same URL in **next field name** (Site Address (URL))

and then **Hit Save button**.

Congratulation your website redirected successfully.

Comment: Thanks. But as mentioned, it is a hybrid WordPress/Static HTML site. This does not fix my issue.